# How can I forward service worker `console.log`s to stdout in the terminal?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, service-worker

Having quite some difficulty debugging service workers in a Puppeteer automation for browser extensions. Is there a way to forward the service worker (working with manifest v3, that's why my extension has a service worker) to the stdout of the terminal so I can see some logs while I run my scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same need as you, and actually it's not implemented yet in Puppeteer.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/packages/puppeteer-core/src/common/Target.ts#L186-L200), there is a TODO saying "Make workers send their console logs", with a noop (`() => {}`) for the callback of the [`Runtime.consoleAPICalled`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#event-consoleAPICalled) event. This TODO was introduced with [this PR](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/4397) in 2019.

Currently, the event [is listened to](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/9e9577459614fb1481899e8e939c2984f4661ca7/packages/puppeteer-core/src/common/WebWorker.ts#L91-L100), but not re-emitted as a Puppeteer event. So you'll have to do it manually:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(...)

const serviceWorkerTarget = await this.browser.waitForTarget(
  (target) => target.type() === 'service_worker'
)

const serviceWorker = await serviceWorkerTarget.worker()
serviceWorker._client.on('Runtime.consoleAPICalled', (message) => {
  console[message.type](message)
})
```

Which will log something as:

```js
{
  type: 'log',
  args: [
    {
      type: 'string',
      value: 'Hello World'
    }
  ],
  executionContextId: 1,
  timestamp: 42.000,
  stackTrace: { callFrames: [ [Object] ] }
}
```

---

**Update:** If you want to log uncaught exception too, add this:

```js
serviceWorker._client.on(
    'Runtime.exceptionThrown',
    ({exceptionDetails}) => {
      const text = `${exceptionDetails.text}${exceptionDetails.exception?.description ?? ''}`
      console.error(text)
    }
  )
```

Comment: This is accurate, thanks!